# jquery ajax success loading js

Tags: jquery, google-plus

I tried to add google plus button in an `jquery ajax page`, I met some trouble.

my code caused `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` and failed loadind js to an ajax page.  So how to solve? Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url, 
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data, 
  success: function(html){
    $('#result').html(html);
    $('#googleplus').html('<g:plusone href="'+window.parent.document.URL+'" size="tall"></g:plusone>');
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
  }
});
```

Comment: And which line caused that error?

Comment: @Juhana, not in my code, but in `googleapis.client__plusone.js:82` then failed laoding google plus button.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the callback function for $.getscript to insert the button after the script is loaded.

Edited my answer, was thinking of same origin policies, but json should be possible cross domain with getscript.

have no idea if it works, but try:

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js", function () {
    $('#googleplus').html('<g:plusone href="'+window.parent.document.URL+'" size="tall"></g:plusone>');
});
```

EDIT: Actually just tested this myself, and this works fine, +1 for me.

Editing again, if it still does not work, one of your variables are wrong or you are trying to insert the button into a div that does not exist, yet.
To make sure the div exists, and if it's in the html your using with Ajax, you could call the function on the complete handler, like so:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url, 
   dataType: "html",
   type: 'POST',
   data: data, 
   success: function(html){
       $('#result').html(html);
   },
   complete: function() {
       $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js", function () {
           $('#googleplus').html('<g:plusone href="'+window.parent.document.URL+'" size="tall"></g:plusone>');
       });
   }

});
```

After that you should check your vars, see what window.parent.document.URL returns in an alert. I'm asuming your using an iFrame, otherwise it would be just window.location.href, wich is what I used when testing the above code without an iFrame.

Inside an iFrame parent.location.href usually does the trick.

Hopefully last edit, did some testing, and using your code results in the same error as the one you reported. I was assuming you were doing something inside an iFrame, if your not you should use:

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js", function () {
    $('#googleplus').html('<g:plusone href="'+window.location.href+'" size="tall"></g:plusone>');
});
```

Comment: so do u have any idea, how can I add `plusone button` in ajax page?